# R - differences between cindex function from pec package and coxph

Tags: r, survival-analysis, roc

I'm comparing the cindex function from the pec package with the resulting concordance index from coxph (survival package).

1) First the results between these two functions are different

```
library(pec)
library(survival)
library(prodlim)

# Simulate survival data
set.seed(12)
dat <- SimSurv(1000)

# C-index from coxph    
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~X1+X2, data=dat)
summary(mod1)$concordance[1]

0.846249

# C-index from cindex    
cindex(mod1,formula=Surv(time,status)~X1+X2,data=dat)

           AppCindex  Pairs Concordant
coxph.model        83 915194     759712
```

2) If I use a counting process format, the cindex function give me an error

```
data(Melanoma)
# Calculate age at entry
Melanoma$age_entry <- Melanoma$age-(Melanoma$time/365.25)
# Use just one outcome (no competing risk scenario)
Melanoma$out <- ifelse(Melanoma$status==1,1,0) 

mod1 <- coxph(Surv(age_entry,age,out)~ulcer+thick, data=Melanoma)
summary(mod1)$concordance[1]

0.7661805 

cindex(mod1,formula=Surv(age_entry,age,out)~ulcer+thick,data=Melanoma)

Error: is.null(entry) | all(entry <= time) is not TRUE
```

Does anyone have a clue why 1) the two C-indexes are different and 2) if it possible to use a counting process format in the cindex function?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Re: 1) coxph::concordance differs from pec::cindex

It looks like **ties are handled differently by default when computing the
C-index between these two**.

Formula in `coxph` (see `?survConcordance()`):

```
(agree + tied/2)/(agree + disagree + tied).
```

Formula in `pec::cindex`:

```
agree/(agree + disagree)
```

Try computing these manually from the outputs for `pec::cindex`. For `coxph`,
obtain the agree/disagree numbers with this formula (via `?survConcordance`):

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x1, data=df)
survConcordance(Surv(time, status) ~predict(fit), df)
```

### References

`?coxph.object` has:

> concordance: the concordance, as computed by survConcordance.

`?survConcordance` has:

> The final concordance is (agree + tied/2)/(agree + disagree + tied).

NOTE: read the full help file for **important notes on these ties**.

I got pec's formula by manually checking the numbers.